# DIVI Theme Options customization lost

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

We have about 50 websites with DIVI theme and our inhouse custom child theme which we rarely change. We have been facing issue for the few websites where changes done using Theme Options, Theme Builder or Theme Customizer are reverted after few days for some strange reason even if we redo those changes. And we started facing this issue since last month.

Our websites are hosted on Cloudways Digital Ocean.

Wordpress Version : 6.2.1

DIVI Version : Version: 4.21.0

Following are the list of plugins we are currently using:
Advanced Custom Fields PRO : Version 6.1.6
Advanced Custom Fields: ACF Code Field : Version Version 1.8
Advanced Custom Fields: Font Awesome : Version 4.0.5
Better Font Awesome : Version 2.0.4
Bot Protection : Version 4.97
Business Hours Indicator : Version 2.3.9
Font Awesome : Version 4.3.2
Real Testimonials : Version 2.6.4
Smart Slider 3 : Version 3.5.1.15
Snazzy Maps : Version 1.4.0
Testimonial Slider and Showcase : Version 2.3.2
W3 Total Cache : Version 2.3.2
Wordfence Security : Version 7.9.2
XML Sitemap & Google News : Version 5.3.3
Yoast SEO : Version 20.7

Has anyone faced similiar issue? Could you help me on how to debug the issue?